# Including a dynamic snippet multiple times in the template

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have a simple snippet, that I would like to repeat all over my website (and sometimes multiple times per page):

```
<div class="snippet-css">
  <h1>{% block snippet-header %}{% endblock %}</h1>

  <div class="snippet-content">
  {% block snippet-content %}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <div class="snippet-footer">
  {% block snippet-footer%}{% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to include this snippet several times in the same page, each time replacing the snippet-header, snippet-content and snippet-footer blocks with unique content.

Defining a django tag which would accept both three blocks as arguments doesn't look good to me (HTML code locked inside the Django tag):

```
{% generate_snippet heading content footer %}
```

I also found this blog post

http://powertwenty.com/blog/index.php/python/repeating_sections_in_a_django_template

which deals with the problem by splitting the snippet into several tags.

What is the best way to achieve this result with Django templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass values to Django's built-in `{% include %}` template tag like this:

```
{% include "snippet.html" with header="blah" content="content" footer="lalala" %}
```

You can also pass variables:

```
{% include "snippet.html" with header=var1 content=var2 footer=var3 %}
```

Then in snippet.html:

```
<div class="snippet-css">
  <h1>{{ header }}</h1>

  <div class="snippet-content">
  {{ content }}
  </div>

  <div class="snippet-footer">
  {{ footer }}
  </div>
</div>
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: This can work, if there's a way in Django how to define variables in the template (that are multiline mix of pure HTML and template code). E.g. snippet-content can get quite complicated (containing for loops and who knows what other magic).

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to use an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) - you can define any variables you like in the tag, and they will be passed on to the template fragment for rendering.

Comment: agree - inclusion tag is a good alternative to `{% include %}` and makes multiple inclusions less messy